# Join many tables to one [Many-to-many and with extra columns] using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

Could you help me please, using hibernate and annotations I want to join 4 tables (prof, salle , groupe, cours) with another one (creneau). the 4 of them have a many-to-many relationship with the 5th table.

I googled it, I know that with many-to-many relationship (I found only the case of 2 tables ) will create a link table to join them, it contains their keys (in my case there will be extra columns also)

This is the best link I found [Join Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/). The solution that I found more appropriate to the problem would be to repeat that tutorial for the 4 tables (prof-creneau)/(salle/creneau) ....
and with the same link table.

Is it the best way to achieve it (for me it seems repetitive) ?

Comment: i don't see it bad :S ,you mean something like inheritance that sounds worst to me, but im not an expert in hibernate

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on your schema. Are you saying that there are 4 distinct many-to-many relationships (prof-creneau, salle-creneau, groupe-creneau, and cours-creneau)? Or are you saying that they can all be many-to-many with each other (prof-salle, prof-groupe, salle-groupe, etc.), or that there are distinct combos of all five (prof-salle-groupe-cours-creneau)?

Answer (score 0):

Classic @ManyToMany relationship refers between TWO entities.

If you want many-to-many table relationship, with extra column you need join table.

Here is useful example:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned in my comment on your answers, I'm not 100% clear, but I'm guessing you have four distinct many-to-many relationships:

1. prof-creneau
2. salle-creneau
3. groupe-creneau
4. cours-creneau

If that is the case, then your guess is correct. The best way to achieve it is to have four separate many-to-many relationships. This means you will have four join tables (one for each relationship, each one has two columns; a foreign key for creneau and a foreign key for the other table in the relationship).

In Hibernate you would specify all of these mappings separately.

Your DAO classes could look something like:

```
public class Prof {
    private Set<Creneau> creneaus = ...;
}

public class Salle {
    private Set<Creneau> creneaus = ...;
}

public class Groupe {
    private Set<Creneau> creneaus = ...;
}

public class Cours {
    private Set<Creneau> creneaus = ...;
}

public class Creneau {
    private Set<Prof> profs = ...;
    private Set<Salle> salles = ...;
    private Set<Groupe> groupes = ...;
    private Set<Cours> courss = ...;
}
```

It may seem repetitive, but you *do* have four separate relationships here.

Comment: That's my case, I was just wondering if there is a better way to do it. Thank you

Comment: Nope! Unfortunately, that's what you've got to do. :) By the way, if it's appropriate for you, you can set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property in your Hibernate configuration to automatically create the database tables (including join tables) for you based on your mapping. This can be useful for initial development - **do not leave it in during production**. See table 3.7 at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional